# How to print key-value from JSON array using a loop in Kotlin?

Tags: android, loops, kotlin

I am using an API which gives me a JSON response. From this JSON I have created model classes. In these classes. These are my model classes:

```
class Json3(
    val result : Result3){}

class Result3(
    val pic1:String,
    val item_name:String,
    val shop_name: String,
    val item_size:List<ItemSize>,
    val item_description:String,
    val price:String ){}

class ItemSize(
    val name:String,
    val value:String){}
```

I want to access the name and value from item size and print them. How can I achieve that with a loop ?
This is my JSON:

```
{"result": {

"product_id": 283946,
"shop_rating": 5,
"shop_reviews_count": 476,
"occasion_id": 94,
"section_id": 1,
"section": "Flower",
"pickup": false,
"preparation_time": "0 mins",
"is_favorite": false,
"item_sold_by": "Quantity",

"item_size": [
  {
    "name": "Height",
    "value": "29cm"
  },
  {
    "name": "Width",
    "value": "52cm"
  }
]
```

From the item_size, I would like to access the values and print something like this with the help of some loop: Height:29cm/ Width:52cm. This is what I've tried so far. I am only getting the last name and value when I set it to  itemsizename.
But I want all the name and values from the array. For example: Height:29cm/ Width:52cm and Length if it will be available further.

```
val obj = JSONObject(json)
                val getObject = obj.getJSONObject("result")
                val getArray = getObject.getJSONArray("item_size")
val obj = JSONObject(json)
                val getObject = obj.getJSONObject("result")
                val getArray = getObject.getJSONArray("item_size")
                for (i in 0 until getArray.length()) {
                    val objects: JSONObject = getArray.getJSONObject(i)
                   val     parameter = objects["name"].toString()
                  val   parameterValue = objects["value"].toString()
itemsizename.text = parameter + ": " + parameterValue }
```

Comment: show us your json response?

Comment: Done. Please have a look.

Comment: Hi @sara seen your updated for loop code, apparently the code will override the values and show the last item of the list, you can use recyclerview to print all values

Comment: Can you tell me how ? Is there any other loop that I can use instead of recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

First get the item_size JSONArray from your response JSONObject

```
val item_sizeJsonArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("item_size")
```

Step 2: -
update your Result3 class and let item_size to be a list instead of Array

```
val item_size:List<ItemSize>,
```

use the below for loop to get the ItemSize List, passing the item_sizeJsonArray

```
fun getItemSizeList(itemsJsonList:JSONArray): List<ItemSize> {
    val items: ArrayList<ItemSize> = ArrayList()
    for (i in 0 until itemsJsonList.length()) {
        val obj = itemsJsonList[i] as JSONObject
        val name: String = obj.getString("name")
        val value: String = obj.getString("value")
        val item = ItemSize(name, value)
        items.add(item)
    }
    return items
}
```

or you can use Gson

```
fun getItemSizeListWithGson(itemsJsonList: JSONArray): List<ItemSize> {
val items: ArrayList<ItemSize> = ArrayList()
for (i in 0 until itemsJsonList.length()) {
    val item = Gson().fromJson(itemsJsonList[i].toString(), ItemSize::class.java)
    items.add(item)
}
return items
```

}

Plain for loop

```
 val item_sizeJsonArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("item_size")

    for (i in 0 until item_sizeJsonArray.length()) {
                val obj = item_sizeJsonArray[i] as JSONObject
                val name: String = obj.getString("name")
                val value: String = obj.getString("value")
               
            }
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it without a function ? I just want a for loop to get the value for "name" and "value" and give that to a string. So  I can use the string.

Comment: Hi @sara I have updated the answer to include the for loop you can use, please check and let me know if that works for you

Comment: what is itemsJsonList[i] in the for loop ?

Comment: Sorry I have updated the code - to -> item_sizeJsonArray

Comment: I have tried another for loop which is working. But it always saves the last name and value when I try to print it whereas I want all the name and values to be printed. Can you tell me how to achieve that ?